Type describing a generic protocol with constraints
Given the following python code:
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar


class A: pass
class B(A): pass
class C(A): pass


T = TypeVar("T", B, C, contravariant=True)


class X(Protocol[T]):
    def f(self, t: T) -> None: ...


class XTImpl(X[T]):
    def f(self, t: T) -> None: pass


class XBImpl(X[B]):
    def f(self, t: B) -> None: pass

How can I type a variable that accepts only a XTimpl instance and not XBImpl instances ?
My true use case is that I have functions
def fB(x: type[X[B]]): ...

def fC(x: type[X[C]]): ...


def fT(x):
    fB(x)
    fC(x)

And I would like to type argument x in fT so that only XTImpl is accepted. fB is expected to accept both XTImpl and XBImpl.
I would like something like just X for instance (for which I get error "Expected type arguments for generic class").
If we changed T = TypeVar("T", B, C, contravariant=True) into T = TypeVar("T", A, contravariant=True) then we could just use X[A].
But in my true use case, B and C are not direct children of a common ancestor.

How is fT() used and fB()/fT() implemented? What kind of argument is expected to be accepted by both functions?

fB is expected to accept XBImpl and XTImpl.
fT is expected to accept only XTImpl.
This is of course a simplification of a more complicated code. In my true use case, fB and fT append to some dictionaries that act as registries for later call in the code

I can see why this caused you difficulty, the contravariant condition on T proved troublesome. The solution I have below is essentially a placeholder for an intersection type in fT. Since T is limited to only two values, we can use overloads to describe each available option:

@overload
def fT(x: type[XTImpl[B]]):
    ...

@overload
def fT(x: type[XTImpl[C]]):
    ...

def fT(x: type[XTImpl[Any]]):
    fB(x)
    fC(x)

The interior of the function fT has a slightly broader type than it should (note the use of Any here), but by overloading at least the exterior interior of fT should now be correct. Hope this helps!

Thank you for your answer. I don't understand the use of the overloads, my type checker is happy without the overloaded fT defintions.
I don't think Any is too broad here as if I try to define
class XIntImpl:
    def f(self, t: int): pass

Then the type checker correctly refuses fT(XIntImpl) as we specified that T should be only B or C.
So the Any inside XTImpl seems not to be a real Any, but an Any translated in terms of T

So it does make some difference if you compare these two:
class XIntImpl1(XTImpl[B]):     def f(self, t: B):         pass and class XIntImpl2(XTImpl[int]):     def f(self, t: int):         pass
Although the second one is banned anyway really from the spec of XTImpl
